# Interactive calendar with javascript

Tags: javascript, calendar

I'm currently working on my school project which is interactive calendar, and I'm stuck with a problem. I need to make my calendar highlight a cell in table, depending on current day. For example: tomorrow is 17th so i want 17th cell to highlight in any color. I need to use just javascript and html to make it. I have table with 31 td selectors written in HTML. 
I was wondering about something like this: **document.getElementsByTagName("td")[Current_Day].setAttribute("background-color", "red");**

Comment: You would be better to add a highlight class to the desired d and have the styling related to that class to change the backgrund color - its always better to separate the styling from the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Coincidentally, I did something like this a few years ago:

https://github.com/Subterrane/calendar

This example code isn't the prettiest (transpiled from Typescript) but essentially, you are correct. Find the day, set the color.

```js
"use strict";
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var calendars = document.getElementsByTagName('calendar');
  for (var ix = 0; ix < calendars.length; ix++) {
    var calendarEl = calendars[ix];
    var now = new Date();
    var y = parseInt(calendarEl.getAttribute('year')) || now.getFullYear();
    var m = parseInt(calendarEl.getAttribute('month')) || now.getMonth() + 1;
    var d = parseInt(calendarEl.getAttribute('day')) || now.getDate();
    var time = new Date(y, m - 1, d);
    var month = time.getMonth();
    var week = 1;
    var day = 1;
    var html = "<year number=\"" + y + "\"><month number=\"" + m + "\"><week number=\"" + week + "\">";
    time.setDate(day);
    do {
      if (time.getDay() % 7 === 0)
        html += "</week><week number=\"" + ++week + "\">";
      html += "<day number=\"" + day + "\"></day>";
      time.setDate(++day);
    } while (month === time.getMonth());
    html += '</week></month>';
    calendarEl.innerHTML = html;
    calendarEl.querySelector('day[number="' + d + '"]').classList.add('today');
  }
  var days = document.querySelectorAll('day');
  for (var ix = 0; ix < days.length; ix++) {
    days[ix].addEventListener('click', dayClicked);
  }
});

function dayClicked() {
  var el = this;
  var data = {
    year: el.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('number'),
    month: el.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('number'),
    week: el.parentElement.getAttribute('number'),
    day: el.getAttribute('number')
  };
  var event = new CustomEvent('calendarClicked', {
    'detail': data
  });
  document.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

```css
calendar {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  max-width: 600px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

week {
  display: flex;
}

week:first-child {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

day {
  flex-basis: 14.3%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 2%;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 4vw;
}

day::after {
  content: attr(number);
}

.today {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <calendar></calendar>
</div>
```